How to set up Token Verification With HAProxy and an Azure App Registration?
I would like to use HAProxy in order to filter any requests that doesn't have a valid JWT generated by an App Registration on Microsoft Entra ID
As for now, I've been able to check almost everything from the JWT. I can check the Algorithm, Issuer, Audience, and if its expired or not.
I would also like to check the signature of the JWT but I've been failing on that task.
I've read the documentation but couldn't make it work.
This is what I got so far
  # get payload part of the JWT
  http-request set-var(txn.iss) http_auth_bearer,jwt_payload_query('$.iss')
  http-request set-var(txn.aud) http_auth_bearer,jwt_payload_query('$.aud')
  http-request set-var(txn.exp) http_auth_bearer,jwt_payload_query('$.exp','int')
  http-request set-var(txn.scope) http_auth_bearer,jwt_payload_query('$.scope')
  
  
  # Validate the JWT
  acl algorithm var(txn.alg) -m str RS256
  acl issuer var(txn.iss) -m str https://sts.windows.net/<tenant-id>/
  acl audience var(txn.aud) -m str <audience>
  acl expired var(txn.exp),sub(txn.now) -m int lt 0  
  acl pbkey http_auth_bearer,jwt_verify(txn.alg,"/pubkey.pem") -m int 1


doesn't care what I put into pubkey.pem, I can't make it work.
Inspected the JWT with https://jwt.io/ and got the "kid": "z1rsYHHJ9-8mggt4HsZu8BKkBPw". Then went to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys and looked for the one is using, but I'm not sure what jwt_verify is expecting on the file.
Decode the json to get a public key and use the x5c property to use it as a cert like
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANB...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

and
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDlzC...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

but none of them worked properly.
At this point I'm kinda lost.
What is jwt_verify exactly expecting?

jwt_verify in HAProxy expects the public key in PEM format, not the certificate. You should extract the public key from the x5c field in the JSON response, remove the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- lines, and use the public key directly.

yes I already tried it, tried again just to be sure, but it still doesn't work :/
